# Who aside for Avraham and Adam in the torah died prematurely before their destined years?

Tags: death, age

I know Abraham died early because of Aisuv, 
Adam because of David.

Who aside from them died prematurely, i.e. before their destined years?

Comment: תנו רבנן ארבעה מתו בעטיו של נחש ואלו הן בנימין בן יעקב ועמרם אבי משה וישי אבי דוד וכלאב בן דוד  Everyone except those four

Comment: What about Chanoch?

Answer (score 4):

Yaakov because of his complaint to Par'o about why he looked so haggard and old (Vayigash 47:9). Yosef died at 110 (Vayigash 50:26 the first of the brothers to die) because of the strains of being the leader as did Yehoshua.  Shmuel Hanavi and Shlomo Hamelech died at the age of fifty two for the same reason. This is from memory of meforshim of the appropriate pesukim.

Note that in general, leaders (especially good ones) tend to die relatively young because of the pressure of the office.

Comment: ואמר רב יהודה שלשה דברים מקצרים ימיו ושנותיו של אדם מי שנותנין לו ס''ת לקרות ואינו קורא כוס של ברכה לברך ואינו מברך והמנהיג עצמו ברבנות ס''ת לקרות ואינו קורא דכתיב {דברים ל-כ} כי הוא חייך ואורך ימיך כוס של ברכה לברך ואינו מברך דכתיב {בראשית יב-ג} ואברכה מברכיך והמנהיג עצמו ברבנות דא''ר חמא בר חנינא מפני מה מת יוסף קודם לאחיו מפני שהנהיג עצמו ברבנות

Comment: +1 for answer (and beating me too it). Re your last paragraph, I guess that explains why Jimmy Carter is still alive :-(

Comment: @DanF I was going to mention how the presidents age so drastically during their terms of office and then "recover" after they leave office and can no longer  do anything significant (at least in modern times).